# angular 2 update object array inside observable subscribe

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angular2-observables

I am trying to update object array inside observable subscribe method. But it is not updating as expecting.
My implementation is as follows.
Compoent.ts

```
constructor(private shopHomeService: ShopHomeService) {

    this.shopHomeService.shopItemChanged.subscribe(
      (item) => {
        if (item) {
          this.items = shopHomeService.getShopItems();
          if (this.items.length > 0) {
            const findItem = this.items.find(shopItem => shopItem.Id === item.Id);
            if (findItem) {
              findItem.OrderQuantity = findItem.OrderQuantity + 1;
            } else {
              this.items.push(item);
            }
          } else {
            this.items.push(item);
          }
          this.items = this.items.slice();
          shopHomeService.ShopItems = this.items;
          this.shopItems = [];
          this.shopItems = this.items;
        }

      }
    );
  }
```

Service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()

    export class ShopHomeService {
      private shopItems = [];
      private shopItem: any;
      shopItemChanged = new BehaviorSubject<any>(this.shopItem);

      constructor() { }

      getShopItems() {
        console.log(this.shopItems);
        return this.shopItems;
      }

      set ShopItems(shopItems) {
        this.shopItems = shopItems;
        console.log(this.shopItems);
      }

      addShopItem(item) {
        item.OrderQuantity = 1;
        item.Discount = 0;
        item.DiscountPercentage = 0;
        this.shopItemChanged.next(item);
      }

      removeShopItem(item) {
        this.shopItems = this.shopItems.filter(element => element.Id !== item.Id);
        this.shopItemChanged.next(this.shopItems);
      }

    }
```

Initially **OrderQuantity** property set to 1 in every objects of the array items.
When same type of object adding to shopItems it will increase value of OrderQuantity by 1. Logic has implemented above code. But when shop items change it always gives object array with **OrderQuantity = 1**. (**shopHomeService.getShopItems()** returns array list with OrderQuantity = 1, but when the **shopHomeService.ShopItems** call it sent rderQuantity = 2)